# vscode typing autocompletion not working

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm having issues with vscode (regular and insiders) and it's inability to provide any sort of autocompletion. I tried downloading the depreciated tsd project and install the typings files that way, as well as via typings.

For the reference, I've tried both relative paths and simply inserting `typings/express.d.ts` (regular vscode highlights this as an error stating that the path does not exist).

For insiders I'm running on 1.1.0 and for regular release it's 0.10.11.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe that I have it figured out. Adding `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports":true` to jsconfig.json solved the problem and you don't need a typescript reference at the top of your files.